# Using sed for multiple matches instead matching whole file

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have file as

```
0::question#1::
Love
giberrish fdfd

1::anything#2:
Is
repeat

22::anything#3::
Lie
```

I want to extract

```
Love
giberish
****
Is 
repeat
****
Lie
```

`cat file.txt | sed 's/::\n([^\n]*)/\1/g'`

I'm getting file as

```
0::question#1::
Love

1::anything#2:
Is

22::anything#3::
Lie
```

On testing regex is matching here
https://regex101.com/

**UPDATE** 
I missed to tell, that file extract is for for multi-line not single line and also i want a deliminator as well. I apologize for trouble

`cat org_op.2019.04.06-09.43.59 | sed 's/^.*::.*//g;/^$/d'`

I get output as

```
Love
giberrish fdfd
Is
repeat 2 4 4
Lie
```

So I added some `deliminator`  in order to split one record from another

`cat org_op.2019.04.06-09.43.59 | sed 's/^.*::.*/***/g;/^$/d'`

and got

```
 ***
Love
giberrish fdfd
 ***
Is
repeat 2 4 4
 ***
Lie
```

To remove top-line i used

`cat org_op.2019.04.06-09.43.59 | sed 's/^.*::.*/ ***/g;/^$/d' | tail -n +2`

new output is

```
  Love
  giberrish fdfd
  ***
  Is
  repeat 2 4 4
  ***
  Lie
```

I want to capture each record using `awk` i did

`cat org_op.2019.04.06-09.43.59 | sed 's/^.*::.*/ ***/g;/^$/d' | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "***" }{print $1}'`

I get output

```
Love
giberrish fdfd
```

I'm unable to remove last empty line which is same across all fields i tried using pipe to sed with `/^$/d` didn't work

**UPDATE 2**
got it working  by

``sed 's/^.*::.*/***/g;/^$/d' | tail -n +2 | awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "***" }{print $1}' | sed -e '/^$/d'`

Comment: Try this `sed 's/^.*::.*//g' data.txt `!

Comment: It works, splendid, pls have it as answer so i can approve it

Comment: This works better `sed -e '/^.*::.*/d' -e '/^$/d' data.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method of matching lines then remnove those matching lines and then remove the spaces...

```
sed -e '/^.*::.*/d' -e '/^$/d' data.txt
```

Result:

```
Love
Is
Lie
```

Or a shorter version:

```
sed -E '/^(.*::.*)?$/d'
```

Info:

- `'/^.*::.*/d'`: Match lines with `::` and delete them
- `'/^$/d'`: Remove all blank lines

Comment: `/::/d` is a shorter version of your first expression, combined that is: `sed -E '/^(.*::.*)?$/d'`

Comment: interesting didn't know i could use `?` like that!

Comment: please see update!

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
sed '/^[0-9]/d; /^$/d' file.txt
Love
Is
Lie
```

- `/^[0-9]/d`: remove lines starting with a number
- `/^$/d`: remove empty lines

Comment: To combine both in one expression: `sed -E '/^([0-9].*)?$/d'`